# substitution of a row name for a value in a dataframe in r

Tags: r, indexing, gsub, substitution

Ok, so I have this dataframe (829x2) in which the first column is comprised of the row numbers of another matrix. I need to substitute these row numbers with the values (ID numbers) from the second column of the second dataframe (676X2).

Here are the first few rows of dataframe 1 and 2 of the first dataframe

dataframe 1:

```
   Col1(rownames to be replaced)          Col2
X1 167                                 -2.623973e-01
X2 c(14, 275)                          -2.241113e-01
X3 4                                   -3.066684e-01
X4 c(493, 165, 170, 187, 224, 246, 262)-2.369324e-01
X8 c (207, 233, 235, 236, 622, 624)    -8.503367e-02
X10 369                                -2.217171e-01
```

dataframe 2:

```
  Col1      Col2(Data I want replace the rownames)
1 Formic    C00058 
2 Methanoic C00058 
3 Ethanoic  C00033
4 Acetic    C00033
5 Propionic C00163
6 Propanoic C00163
7 Butyric   C00246
```

So, here is what I would like the end product to be (This is just an example the numbers aren't exact)

```
   Col1                              Col2
X1 C00043                          -2.623973e-01
X2 c(C00012, C00125)               -2.241113e-01
X3 C00033                          -3.066684e-01
X4 c(C00023, C00078, etc...)       -2.369324e-01
```

Here is dput() of dataframe 1. KEGGnumber=Col1 Cor=Col2

```
>dput(datamap2[1:10,])
structure(list(KEGGnumber = structure(list(X1 = 167, X2 = c(14, 
275), X3 = 4, X4 = c(493, 165, 170, 187, 224, 246, 262), X8 = c(207, 
233, 235, 236, 622, 624), X10 = 369, X11 = c(207, 233, 235, 236, 
622, 624), X12 = 17, X13 = c(225, 240, 622, 623, 626, 631), X21 = c(447, 
579)), .Names = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X8", "X10", "X11", 
"X12", "X13", "X21")), Cor = c(-0.26239726267789, -0.22411133150271, 
-0.30666840337651, -0.236932418052063, -0.085033673316946, -0.221717142242715, 
-0.23574540607512, -0.254068790827129, -0.410952995109905, 0.0585077720606303
)), .Names = c("KEGGnumber", "Cor"), row.names = c("X1", "X2", 
"X3", "X4", "X8", "X10", "X11", "X12", "X13", "X21"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you `dput` your data frame1? It depends on what kind of data structure you have in each cell of the `Col1`.

Comment: Col1 is formated as a list but i can unlist() it. Can u elaborate on dput? Im not familiar with the fucntion.

Comment: If you paste `dput(dataframe 1)` in your question, it will be much easier for us to help. Use `dput` on your dataframe it will output the actual structure of the dataframe, then you can paste the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using `lapply`:

```
df$KEGGnumber <- lapply(df$KEGGnumber, function(rows) df2$Col2[rows])
df
#        KEGGnumber        Cor
# X1         C00058 -0.2623973
# X2 C00163, C00246 -0.2241113
# X3         C00033 -0.3066684
# X4 C00033, C00033 -0.2369324
```

I modified your data a little bit so that it will makes sense with the dataframe 2 you provided:

```
df
#    KEGGnumber        Cor
# X1          2 -0.2623973
# X2       5, 7 -0.2241113
# X3          4 -0.3066684
# X4       3, 4 -0.2369324

df2
#        Col1   Col2
# 1    Formic C00058
# 2 Methanoic C00058
# 3  Ethanoic C00033
# 4    Acetic C00033
# 5 Propionic C00163
# 6 Propanoic C00163
# 7   Butyric C00246
```

Comment: that works to create the list of ID's that should be df$KEGGnumber, but when I try to set it as df$KEGGnumber, it outputs more numbers and not the ID's.

Comment: Is the `Col2` in your dataframe 2 character? you need to convert it to character like `df2$Col2 <- as.character(df2$Col2)`.

Comment: Yes its class is character

Comment: Here is an example line of Col1 of the new dataframe: `X2  "c(572, 23)"`

Comment: Basically whenever I attempt to change the class of an element the list to a character it gives me a random number, so I cant format the list into a column of the dataframe.

Comment: The only thing I could think of is that the `df2$Col2` might be a factor variable which can mess the result up. Another thing I would check is just to run the right hand side. i.e. `lapply(df$KEGGnumber, function(rows) df2$Col2[rows])` to see if you get what you expect.

Comment: running the right hand side worked! thank you so much for your help. Why was it not working?

Comment: So it has something to do with assigning the list back to the data frame. I am not very sure about the reason, since it is working for me. Might be the R version. What R version are you using? Try to upgrade R if it is too old.

Comment: Im using 3.3.0...hmmm

Comment: Could also be your data. Missing values, unexpected data types. Subset a small sample of your original data would be a good start for debugging.